# How can I get a 2D texture to rotate like a compass in XNA?

Tags: xna, mathematics, rotation

I'm working on a small maze puzzle game and I'm trying to add a compass to make it somewhat easier for the player to find their way around the maze. The problem is: I'm using XNA's draw method to rotate the arrow and I don't really know how to get it to rotate properly. What I need it to do is point towards the exit from the player's position, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

So does anyone know how I can do this? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The secret is `atan2`:

```
Vector2 exitPosition = whatever;
Vector2 currentPosition = whatever;

Vector2 direction = exitPosition - currentPosition;
float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X);
```

[**atan2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx)) gives you the angle of a vector, with the positive X axis being at an angle of zero, and moving in the positive direction towards the positive Y axis (which is π/2). Simply pass this as the `rotation` parameter to `SpriteBatch.Draw` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx)).

Make sure your compass needle texture is pointed the correct way for an angle of zero (ie: to the left), or add an appropriate angular offset in your code. Set the `origin` parameter of the `SpriteBatch.Draw` call to the pivot point of your needle texture.